# qt QML tabviewstyle tab rectangle add x

Tags: qt, qml, tabview

I need to move the tab buttons in tabview to shift or padding right. When I add x position to the tabviewstyle rectangle, it moves to the right but the end tabs are getting cut off. How could I move the tabs without the cut off, Any idea how to fix this?

```
TabView {
    id: frame
    //anchors.fill: parent
    y: 250
    width: 400
    anchors.margins: 4
    Tab { title: "Tab 1" }
    Tab { title: "Tab 2" }
    Tab { title: "Tab 3" }
    
    style: TabViewStyle {
        
        frameOverlap: 1
        tab: Rectangle {
            x: 50
            color: styleData.selected ? "steelblue" :"lightsteelblue"
            border.color:  "steelblue"
            implicitWidth: Math.max(text.width + 4, 100)
            implicitHeight: 20
            radius: 2
            Text {
                id: text
                anchors.centerIn: parent
                text: styleData.title
                color: styleData.selected ? "white" : "black"
            }
        }
        frame: Rectangle { color: "steelblue" }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not completely clear from your description, but if you just want the buttons in the tab bar aligned right, this should do the trick for you:

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-styles-tabviewstyle.html#tabsAlignment-prop

```
TabViewStyle {
    tabsAlignment: Qt.AlignRight
    [...]
}
```

If that's not what you are looking for, can you clarify the question a little more?

EDIT: based on OP's comment below, here's another approach.

Source code for the TabView component is here: https://github.com/qt/qtquickcontrols/blob/dev/src/controls/TabView.qml

You can see it uses a private TabBar component to place the tab buttons at the top of the Tabs stack and supports left, center and right alignment for them.

Perhaps you can achieve the effect you want by setting the anchors.leftMargin on the TabBar? Without it being an aliased property, you'll need to loop on the TabView's children to find it by objectName and then set the anchor margin on it.

Comment: Yes, using tabsAlignment i could place it either left, center or right, but if i want to place in other position (some where inbetween left and center alignment). It seems, it is not possible.

Comment: Ok, see my update on how to find the TabBar and set a leftMargin on its anchoring.